# como hacer la conexion java por xml utilizando jdni

Tags: java, mysql, sql, xml, javafx

necesito que la conexion sea a una db y no temporal como esta en el momento

```
Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at
http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
```

-->

http://docs.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema/datasources_1_0.xsd">
   
    
        jdbc:h2:mem:jboss-javaee-sdstrp;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
        h2
        
            sa
            sa

Answer (score 0):

Modifica el tipo de conexión desde:

```
<connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:jboss-javaee-sdstrp;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
```

a:

```
<connection-url>jdbc:h2:[file:][<path>]:jboss-javaee-sdstrp;
  DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
```

Como se muestra en [H2 Database URL Overview](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#connection_modes).

Comment: Grcs por la guia.. disculpa la pregunta.. podrias indicarme que estructura manejaria el path.. para hacer la conexion hacia afuera.. jdbc:h2:tcp://<server>[:<port>]/[<path>]<databaseName> con un ejemplo a una db mysql podrias ayudarme..Gracias..